# Points on a diagonal and a side of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

ABCD is a parallelogram. Points $N$ and $M$ lie on $CO$ and $BC$, respectively, such that $$CN:NO=CM:MB=3:1.$$ If $\vec{AB}=\vec{a}$ and $\vec{AD}=\vec{b}$, then what $\vec{MN}$ is equal to?

[image]

We can write $\vec{MN}$ as $$\vec{MN}=\vec{CN}-\vec{CM}.$$ Now $$CN=\dfrac{3}{4}\vec{CO}=\dfrac{3}{4}.\dfrac{1}{2}\vec{CA}=\dfrac{3}{8}\vec{CA}=-\dfrac{3}{8}\vec{AC}=-\dfrac{3}{8}\left(\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right)$$
$$\vec{CM}=\dfrac{3}{4}\vec{CB}=-\dfrac{3}{4}\vec{BC}=-\dfrac{3}{4}\vec{b}$$
We got that $$\vec{MN}=-\dfrac{3}{8}\left(\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right)-\dfrac{3}{4}\vec{b}=-\dfrac{3}{8}\vec{a}-\dfrac{9}{8}\vec{b}$$ The given answer in my book is $$\vec{MN}=\dfrac{3}{8}\left(\vec{b}-\vec{a}\right)$$

Comment: $\vec{MN}=-\dfrac{3}{8}\left(\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right)-\dfrac{3}{4}\vec{b}$, do you see the mistake?

Comment: It should have been $+ \dfrac{3}{4} \vec b$

Comment: @MathLover, silly me. Thank you!